# expected number of edges for fixed min cut

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, max-flow-min-cut, random-graphs

It is known that a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ nodes and min cut $k$, must have at least $\frac{1}{2}nk$ edges.

Are there any tighter bounds or expectations I can place on $|E|$ if I assume that $G$ follows a particular random graph model? Or if it is bipartite?

Comment: If you assume that $G$ is bipartite then the bound is tight you can consider $k$-regular graph.

Comment: thanks! do you have a reference for this? is it from Bollobàs 'Random Graphs' book?